# Debug into asp.net Identity open source code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity, membership

I want to be able to debug into the Asp. Net Identity open source code https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity to better understand it.

How do I do it?

I did the following

1. I created a new ASP.Net MVC project (.Net Framework) using VS 2017 community edition
2. Downloaded the source code from https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity
3. Deleted reference to the Identity and Entityframework Identity DLLs from the MVC project and added the downloaded corresponding projects into the solution and referred to them
4. Interestingly neither the extracted open source Identity solution compiles nor mine does.

Can anyone pls put the steps? I guess I want to do the same for Asp.Net Core Identity and also customize the ApplicationUser class to add a salt field for example.

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why negative vote?